# Unsupported joists in attic?

Tags: attic, joists, structural

In my attic there is a beam that ends 80% of the way through. A few of the joists are connected with nails but are unsupported laterally. Should these joists have better support?

[image]

Comment: What is below? That looks like a wall that the beam and joists are resting on. If there’s no wall there, then I’m surprised the ceiling hasn’t fallen yet.

Comment: "Should these joists have better support?" Probably not, if they are used for supporting the *ceiling*. If you intend to use them as attic *floor* joists then you are using them in a way that the structure was not designed for and nobody can answer the question without having a good look at the overall framing layoutof the entire area.

Comment: Is it safe to put plywood over this area to provide easier maintenance access to the furnace?

Comment: Given that it's a tiny amount of additional work, I'd add blocking between the joists where they lap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my mind, it comes down to what's under that beam and ceiling joists.  There should be a wall under the joists (looks like that may be the case 'cause you can see what looks to be the top plate of the wall under the joists), and a built up post of some sort under the edge of the beam.

If those conditions are met, than you should be OK to put down the plywood over the joists.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is good but if, for some crazy reason, there wasn't a structure below those two joist connections then adding plywood would be better than not, because the ply would span and sister multiple joists.

Comment: Potentially yes, @Matthew, however, horizontal spaces tend to collect more than just dust, which could be dangerous. If it were _my_ ceiling and I were to add plywood for strength, I'd build a 2x4 pyramid above it to discourage placing things (like people) there, and attach a sign to indicate it's not to be load bearing. But, then, I also don't like things going through ceilings...